# Evaluating integral by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral.

$$ \int^{1}_{-1} (e^x+x)^2 \ dx $$

Do i expand it like this $ \int^{1}_{-1} e^{2x} + 2xe^x+x^2 \ dx $

or make it like this $ \int^{1}_{-1} (e^x+x) (e^x+x) \ dx $

and what can i do next ?

Comment: Your first suggestion will work.

Comment: If you have an integral of a sum where some of the summands are trivial to deal with, then it's always a good idea to do that first and try the nontrivial ones alone!

Comment: As an aside, note that integrating $xe^x$ may be easier by looking at $(xe^x)' = xe^x+e^x$ by the product rule. Then, $\int xe^x = \int [(xe^x)' - e^x] = xe^x - e^x$. It is critical that a math student (and even more so a physics student) can do this in their sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Only the middle term in the expansion needs to be done by parts:
\begin{align}
\int x\Big(e^x \, dx\Big) = \int x\,dv & = xv - \int v\,dx \\[12pt]
& = xe^x - \int e^x\,dx \\[12pt]
& = xe^x - e^x+C
\end{align}

Comment: Where did the 2 go ?

Comment: One can readily prove that $\int_{x\in [a,b]} cf(x) = c\int_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$ (with the proviso that $f$ is integrable), since for $c>0$, we have $L(cf,P) = cL(f,P)$ and $U(cf,P)= cU(f,P)$. For $c<0$, consider $L(cf,P) = cU(f,P)$ and $U(cf,P) = cL(f,P)$. Now, by integrability of $f$, we can squeeze and get that $c\cdot f$ is integrable by choosing $\epsilon' = \epsilon/c$ and by comparison we have our conclusion.

Comment: @Tennisman : The "$2$" went to the same place where the other terms in the sum went.  We had $\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\,dx + 2\  \underbrace{\int x e^x\,dx} + \int x^2\,dx$.  I was working only on the part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You can expand it and integrate. I will show how I would do this step by step.
$$\int(e^x+x)^2 \ dx$$
$$=\int e^{2x}+2xe^x+x^2 \ dx$$
$$=\int e^{2x} \ dx + \int 2xe^x \ dx + \int x^2 \ dx$$
Lets work on each integral one by one. Lets start with $\displaystyle \int e^{2x} \ dx$. We will use u-substitution for this one.
$$\int e^{2x} \ dx$$
$$u = 2x$$
$$du = 2 \ dx$$
$$\int e^{2x} \ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{e^u}{2} \ du$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int e^u \ du$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}e^u + C$$
$$=\frac{e^u}{2} + C$$
$$=\frac{e^{2x}}{2} + C$$
Now lets work on $\displaystyle \int 2xe^x \ dx$. This will use integration by parts.
$$\int 2xe^x \ dx$$
$$u = 2x$$
$$dv = e^x$$
$$v = e^x$$
$$du = 2$$
$$\int 2xe^x \ dx$$
$$=2xe^x - \int 2e^x \ dx$$
$$=2xe^x - 2\int e^x \ dx$$
$$=2xe^x - 2e^x + C$$
Now the final integral, $\displaystyle \int x^2 \ dx$, is easy. Just use power rule.
$$\int x^2 \ dx = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$
So:
$$\int (e^x + x)^2 \ dx = \frac{e^{2x}}{2} + 2xe^x - 2e^x + \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$
You should know what to do from here. Good luck!